# REST APIs Direct Credit Card in Thailand

Tags: rest, paypal

I am a little bit confused by paypal's document about the countries that supported the DCC payment seen here : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments

Now, that doc tells me that the DCC payment is supported in Thailand but, when I try to enable the DCC payment option in my account's REST API features, it gives me this:

**Note: Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing for your country but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.**

Am I missing something or misunderstood something? And if it indeed not supported in my country, is there any alternative for DCC payment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DCC payments for REST API ("payment_method":"credit_card") can only be used by seller accounts from countries where Website Payments Pro non-hosted is available, for example United States, United Kingdom and Canada.

In a Thai account, you will only be able to use:

"payment_method":"paypal"

which will require a full redirection to PayPal's payment.